# Executing a js file through SCP gives error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: javascript, unix, scp, winscp

I'm trying to execute a js file over SCP with WinSCP, but I'm getting this error to be precise:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`global.sjcl = require('./sjcl-1.0.6');'
```

The code for that part is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

global.sjcl = require('./sjcl-1.0.6');
var password = process.argv[3] || '',
```

Comment: How do you execute a file through SCP?

Comment: I mean using the console tool, and the command given by the developer to use was: ./main.js <path to text file> In my case, I had to change ./ for bash, otherwise I would get a permissions error. Sorry if I don't speak properly, I am an illiterate in this subject.

Comment: First, SCP or WinSCP can't execute commands, so you should describe what you actually do, not throw around some words if you don't know what they mean. Second, the script is not meant to be executed with `bash`, so don't use `bash`. Fix the permissions with `chmod a+x main.js`. If that doesn't solve the issue, you should add the information to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: @RalfFriedl [WinSCP can execute commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command) - Though obviously not with SCP.

Comment: @MarcGonzálezAlcolea Can you execute the command in a regular SSH terminal, like PuTTY?

Answer (score 0):

The file is not meant to be executed with `bash`, it is meant to be executed with `node`. You can see this in the first line, `#!/usr/bin/env node`. When you try to execute it with `bash`, `bash` doesn't recognize the commands and you get the message about the syntax error.

If you don't have execute permissions, you should change that with `chmod a+x main.js`. After that, you will be able to execute the file with `./main.js`.

If you don't want to change the permissions, you can start it with `node main.js`.